# Как сделать правильно запрос в бд взять из одной значеине и поместить его в другой?

Tags: sql

Не могу сообразить как сделать запрос, мне нужно когда я получил id одной базы данных чтобы в другой таблице не учитывали эти записи. Там несколько записей могут быть
Вот пример

```
SELECT * FROM `thema` WHERE `id` <> IN(82,83)
```

Он кривой, но 82,83 и так далее это id получены из другой таблицы. Все они связаны
Тоесть вывести все записи, кроме этих которые вывелась 82,83

Comment: ``WHERE `id` NOT IN (82,83)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соединить две таблицы по id и вывести только те записи, которые на соединились со второй таблицей

```
select
    t.*
from 
    thema t
    left join
    t2 ON t2.id = t.id
where 
    t2.id is null
```